# "Kiu el la du estas la pli forta" aŭ "Kiu el la du estas la plej forta?"

Tags: word-choice

Mi ne certas pri kiu vorto pli taŭgas en la esprimo "El -grupo-, -iu- pli/plej fortas".

Ĉu ambaŭ eblas/ĝustas/samsignifas?

Answer (score 4):

[PMEG has a section about this](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/pli_plej.html#i-me3). It essentially says that when you are comparing only two entities, there is no difference between *la pli* and *la plej*, though it seems to hint that *la pli* is slightly preferred: "*Multaj eĉ opinias... ke* la plej *tiam estas erara. Ĉiuokaze estas ofte pli elegante uzi* la pli."